# How to import data into Excel without automatic connections?

Tags: excel, csv, import, data-connections

I know this might be a simple question but is there an easier way to import a CSV into Excel without it automatically generating a data connection?

I know you can do it by:

- Importing the csv then deleting the connections
- Opening the csv and copying it into your spreadsheet

But I was hoping that there was an easier way to do this.

Note: I want to import it directly into the worksheet at cursor position(much like when you import via data connections) instead of opening another file(where it opens a new worksheet)

Answer (score 3):

In excel 2010 click on the "Data Ribbon". Select the "From Text". Choose you file and click through the text import wizard using settings you'd like. Finally on the "import data" windows click "properties...".

This is the key. Uncheck "Save Query Definition". Click "OK" to accept and then "ok" again on the import data window to import. To check that you didn't make a connection, or delete one that was accidently made, check the "connections" button under the "Data Ribbon". It's a tiny button next to the larger "Refresh All" button.

Answer (score 2):

On Excel 2016 and 365, you just have to delete the connection once your import is completed. This will remove the refreshable possibilities, but not the data. 
I find it simpler than doing copy-paste even if it is not a one-click operation.

[image: Remove connection]

Comment: Seems like a good approach, if only I could find this "Queries & Connections" window/dialog. Could you please add the steps to open it?

Comment: @Socowi - It's on the Data tab of the ribbon, in the "Get & Transform" section, "Show Queries" button. Clicking that button will open the dialog to the side.

Answer (score -1):

You can open a CSV file with "File -> Open" menu in excel. That doesn't open a data connection to CSV.

Comment: but doesn't that just open it as a separate file?